# Can we use two methods with same name and parameters in both parent class and the child class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

In c# can we implement two methods with same name and parameters in both parent class and the child class? If so, how can we call them separately?

Comment: Thank you and sorry for asking a duplicate question. I am new to the stack overflow. I couldn't find it before.